# Testing React Class is Of Type

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to test a react class which renders out several other react classes. All working perfectly apart from i'm not totally sure about the best practise in terms of testing this.

Code:

Parent Class:

```
module.exports = function (deps) {

var MixLink = require('views/components/mixLink')(deps);

return React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div class="packshotData mixesPage" data-view="mixlist">
            {
                this.props.mixes.map(function (mix) {
                    return <MixLink mix={mix} />;
                })
            }
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

};

Child Class:

```
module.exports = function (deps) {

var Link = require('views/components/link')(deps);

var mixLink = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="packshotData-item packshotData-item-overlay">
                <Link className="packshotData-item-link" href={this.props.mix.href} data-control="mixplay">
                    <img className="packshotData-item-image packshotHeadphones" src={this.props.mix.thumbnailHref} />
                    <div className="packshotData-item-title-overlay">
                        <span className="packshotData-item-title-text">{this.props.mix.name}</span>
                    </div>
                </Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

return mixLink;
```

};

Test:

```
describe('mixLinkList Component', function () {

var MixLinkList = require('views/components/mixLinkList')({}),
    MixLink = require('views/components/mixLink')({}),
    TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

it('is a function', function () {
    expect(MixLinkList).to.be.a(Function);
});

it('is create a MixLink for every mix', function () {

    var mixes = [
        {
            href: 'http://mixlink.com/One',
            name: "thunderbirds",
            thumbnailHref: 'someUri'
        },
        {
            href: 'http://mixlink.com/Two',
            name: "captain scarlet",
            thumbnailHref: 'someOtherUri'
        }
    ],
        renderedMixLinkList,
        renderedComponents;

    renderedMixLinkList = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <MixLinkList mixes={mixes} />
    );

    renderedComponents = TestUtils.findAllInRenderedTree(renderedMixLinkList, function (elem) {

        return TestUtils.isCompositeComponentWithType(elem, MixLink);
    });

    expect(renderedComponents.length).to.be(2);
});
```

});

The test currently fails.

I can achieve my goals by grabbing the DOM node and checking the actual HTML which to me seems messy as the HTML produced by MixLink is the concern of MixLink Class not the MixLinkList class.

What i would like to do is simply interrogate the rendered component and check it has two children of type MixLink. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the most part your test seems fine.  I think the reason it's failing is that `MixLinkList` is creating **its own** `MixLink` component **distinct** from the one in the test.  You create one `MixLink` component on line 2 of the parent class, and a different one on line 3 of the test.  So the rendered list does not contain elements of the test's `MixLink`, but rather elements of the list's own link component.

Your method of dependency injection is both the problem and the solution.  Simply change the parent class to begin:

```
module.exports = function (deps) {

var MixLink = deps.MixLink;
```

And the test can then inject the MixLink component like this:

```
var MixLink = require('views/components/mixLink')({}),
    MixLinkList = require('views/components/mixLinkList')({
        MixLink: MixLink
    }),
    TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
```

You might also consider using a more specific TestUtils methods such as `scryRenderedComponentsWithType` ([docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#scryrenderedcomponentswithtype)), which makes the last part of your test read easier:

```
renderedComponents = TestUtils.scryRenderedComponentsWithType(
    renderedMixLinkList,
    MixLink
);
```